# Get mapping between /dev/nvidia* and nvidia-smi gpu list

Tags: gpu, nvidia

A server with 4 GPUs is used for deep learning.
It often happens that GPU memory is not freed after the training process was terminated (killed). Results shown by `nvidia-smi` is

[Nvidia-smi results](https://ibb.co/ggVrmnM)

The cuda device 2 is used. (Might be a process launched with `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=2`)

Some sub-processes are still alive thus occupy the memory.

1. One bruce-force solution is to kill all processes created by python using:

   `pkill -u user_name python`

This should be helpful if there is only one process to be cleaned up.

2. Another solution proposed by pytorch official [My GPU memory isn’t freed properly](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/faq.html)
   One may find them via

   `ps -elf | grep python`.
3. However, if multiple processes are launched and we only want to kill the ones that related to a certain GPU, we can group processes by the gpu index (nvidia0, nvidia1, ...) as:

   `fuser -v /dev/nvidia*`

[fuser -v results](https://ibb.co/vPbjmq2)

As we can see, /dev/nvidia3 is used by some python threads. Thus `/dev/nvidia3` corresponds to `cuda device 2`.

The problem is: I want to kill certain processes launched with setting of `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=2`, but I do not know the gpu index (`/dev/nvidia0, /dev/nvidia1, ...`).

How to find the mapping between `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES={0,1,2,3}` and `/dev/nvidia{0,1,2,3}`.

Comment: Would it help to set `CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER=PCI_BUS_ID`? Then the order should be consistent between CUDA and nvidia-smi.

Comment: This is the answer I want. Would you like to put your comment into the answer region so that I can mark it as accepted and solved. @MartinPecka

Comment: Okay, I'll do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER=PCI_BUS_ID` environment variable, then the order should be consistent between CUDA and nvidia-smi.

There is also another option (if you are sure the limiting to a specific GPU is done via `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` env var). Every process' environment can be examined in `/proc/${PID}/environ`. The format is partially binary, but grepping through the output usually works (if you force grep to treat the file as text file). This might require root privileges.